# Develop OpenGL on Android using C without Renderer

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I developed Open GL project using Java language on Android.This class **GLSurfaceView.Renderer** .

Now, I want to create a NDK project of android developing with OpenGL. 
But I don't like to use **GLSurfaceView.Renderer**. Android's java source is calling C souce in framework. So I think calling open source lib on framework without java VM will run fast than java.

So, is it possible to create an opengl context with a surface view in pure c++ such as NativeActivity for example?

Answer (score 1):

Native c++ interface used to have problem that google didn't promise ABI stability for it. That means your binary would depend on specific version of c++ interface. But simple solution used to be having java initialization code and then use only c++ for rendering path. Minor extra cost for java initialization isn't real concern because that code runs so rarely.

If google has changed ABI stability then you could create a ANativeWindow and pass it to eglCreateWindowSurface.

Comment: I find that cocos2dx uses c++ for developing on android and other OS. I think we can find some way to developing with native c++.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at an Android example called "MoreTeapots". It uses C++ as much as possible and as little Java as possible. It runs everything in a separate thread and communicates with the UI thread to receive events.

However, it won't run faster than Java calling the C++ code in every frame (at least not by the fact that you're not using the Renderer class).